# Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow (Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created a table like `Players` in onCreate() method which is in MySQLiteHelper.java:

```
String CREATE_PLAYERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Players 
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, password TEXT, score INTEGER)";

db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAYERS_TABLE);
```

And I have an update method in the same class like:

```
public int PlayerUpdate(Player PL) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", PL.getName());
    values.put("password", PL.getPassword());
    values.put("score", PL.getScore());

    // 3. updating row
    int i = db.update(TABLE_Players, // table
            values, // column/value
            KEY_ID + " = ?", // selections
            new String[] { String.valueOf(PL.getId()) }); // selection args

    // 4. close
    db.close();

    return i;
}
```

and when I call functions to change `score` variable as:

```
public void scoreUp() {
    helper.PlayerUpdate(new Player(player_name,player_password,player_score+5));
}
public void scoreDown() {
    helper.PlayerUpdate(new Player(player_name,player_password,player_score-5));
}
```

I am getting a logcat error like:

```
Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  
Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Thanks.

### SOLVED:

There has been another query that causes this specific exception and I found out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception comes from accessing cursor columns and the code you posted doesn't show that.

However, column indexing starts from 0, so to access the first column value as string, use `getString(0)` instead of `getString(1)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There was another thing that causes exception and I found that. Thanks for help.